# Why doesn't the engine fire unless I twist the throttle? (Yamaha FZ6 2011)

Tags: motorcycle, starting, sparkplugs, yamaha

This is a question about a motorcycle engine (specifically a Yamaha FZ6 2011, which has electronic fuel injection). Occasionally this happens when I try and turn on the bike: I will press the starter, and the engine turns over, making that characteristic "crackling" sound.

Usually, the engine will ignite after a few "crackles". Sometimes though, it just seems to crank onwards. However if I twist (open) the throttle during this process, the engine starts.

It is not a battery problem as the battery was recently replaced. I believe the spark plugs are due for replacement soon (according to the service manual), but I'm not sure I understand why opening the throttle would make any sort of difference to the starting process.

This doesn't happen all the time. I'd say 80% of the time, the bike starts off normally without me touching the throttle.

Comment: When you open the throttle it prompts the ECU / injection system to add some fuel. The extra fuel is facilitating starting.

Comment: How hot is the engine when the issue occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As dlu pointed out in the comments the extra fuel is what is helping it start. but it could be several reasons why this is needed.

- your injectors might be fouled
- your fuel pressure might be low
- it could be very cold out
- you could have a lean or rich / flooding condition that needs adjusting
- it could be a bad sensor causing the lean condition
- it could be you have aftermarket cams tuned for a high RPM power band giving too much valve overlap

Comment: Good suggestions. I would also suggest checking the air filter(s) for blockage. Low airflow will cause issues too.

Comment: @CharlieRB good point!